Building an azure function v2 (python) with a managed identity (User Defined)
I am following the following tutorial on Azure Functions https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-output?tabs=python-v2%2Cisolated-process%2Cnodejs-v4&pivots=programming-language-python
import logging
import azure.functions as func

app = func.FunctionApp()

@app.function_name(name="BlobOutput1")
@app.route(route="file")
@app.blob_input(arg_name="inputblob",
                path="sample-workitems/test.txt",
                connection="<BLOB_CONNECTION_SETTING>")
@app.blob_output(arg_name="outputblob",
                path="newblob/test.txt",
                connection="<BLOB_CONNECTION_SETTING>")
def main(req: func.HttpRequest, inputblob: str, outputblob: func.Out[str]):
    logging.info(f'Python Queue trigger function processed {len(inputblob)} bytes')
    outputblob.set(inputblob)
    return "ok"

However when I try and use the managed identity that has been created in our AAD. I received the following error.
WARNING: Some http trigger urls cannot be displayed in the output window because they require an authentication token. Instead, you may copy them from the Azure Functions explorer.
Storage account connection string 'AzureWebJobsDefaultEndpointsProtocol=xxx does not exist. Make sure that it is a defined App Setting.
Managed identity user defined has been enabled on this blob storage.
Please can someone specify exactly the steps required to setup a managed identity user assigned with blob storage ?

I was able to solve the issue with https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/blogs/azure-functions-and-managed-identity-more-secrets/

I was able to solve the issue with https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/blogs/azure-functions-and-managed-identity-more-secrets/
By adding these to the configuration setting values:
<CONNECTION_NAME_PREFIX>__blobServiceUri
<CONNECTION_NAME_PREFIX>__queueServiceUri

